# Should you capitalize titles that are questions?

Tags: grammaticality, questions, titles

In my job, we often have to make technical tutorials either as presentations or videos. Some presentations contain slides where a question is a title or the introductory title. For example:

> #27
> In a General Sense, What Do You Believe  Are Some of the Important Factors to Take Into Consideration When Selecting a Routine Expansion Media for iPSC?

The question is, do we have to capitalize it (as we have it written right now), or is it also correct to write it as a sentence (first letter capital, the rest lowercase)? Currently, we inform our colleagues to follow the APA style of capitalization for every title. However, in this case, it is visually difficult to understand with everything capitalized.

Could someone let us know what is grammatically correct?

Comment: I suspect this is more a question of style rather than one of grammaticality. You are free to follow a style guideline or ignore it as you want. Personally, with a multi-line question like the example, I'd treat it as a sentence.

Comment: Grammar doesn't interact significantly with punctuation, for which rules are far less rigorous (especially in peripheral cases such as fragments, parentheticals, and titles). Orwell's Sixth ('avoid the outlandish-looking/reading/sounding') and Grice's maxims (here, 'be clear and uncluttered') are usually paramount. Most would agree that 'polycapitalisation' looks hideous. I don't know whether 'Routine Expansion Media' is usually treated as a proper noun, and 'iPSC' is doubtless invariant, but I'd ditch ...

Comment: all the rest apart from the initial 'I'. [We've had questions on capitalisation of titles before, and the best answer was that unless you're tied to a certain style guide / editor, use common sense, a clear-cut style, and be consistent. Not always achievable, English being English.]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: only commenting to say how much I like the word *polycapitalisation*.  Oh, and to wonder if you should have written *hypercapitalisation*?

Comment: @HPM Yes, there are a few more examples of that in a Google search. I was hoping neither existed.

Comment: If editing, I'd cut back to *Selecting a Routine Expansion Media for iPSC*. There, I'd keep the caps throughout due to the label that refers to a 'thing'. On other slides, not.

Comment: It agree that it looks awful.  It reminds me of the chapter titles in *Pinocchio*.  I get that different style manuals might have tiny differences, but in general this is something that one can generally fix with an online utility where you paste in a title and you get a nicely punctuated version back.  (You might fare better with this level of change than with a more radical proposal to capitalize only the first word.)

Comment: In stylistic terms, it's very bad. "In a General Sense, What Do You Believe Are Some of the Important Factors to Take Into Consideration" is just lots of unnecessary words. If capitals make it hard to understand, the solution is fewer words.